# Custom NavigationDrawer sometimes not working properly

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

I have a custom navigation drawer. I user Support library's DrawerLayout.

My problem is that ONLY sometimes when I click on the hamburger icon, a shadow appears and the side menu (drawer layout) does not get open.

I have tried this solution offered in SO but didn't work:

drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Here is how it looks:

Before clicking on the icon:
[image]

Here is how it looks those SOMETIMES that clicking doesn't work:
[image]

Here is how it looks when everything is working fine:
[image]

Here is my layout file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.parsdigit.helsa.Activity.Main">

<!-- Main Layouts ... -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <FrameLayout
            android:background="@color/blue"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout

                android:id="@+id/fragmentHolder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorGray" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <!-- Laundry Info Layout -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/laundryInfoLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"
                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <include
                            layout="@layout/pin_info_layout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                            android:visibility="visible" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- Invoice Info Layout -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/invoiceInfoLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                    android:background="#25a5cc"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.85"
                        android:background="@drawable/solid_line_2_no_border_less_round"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtSumTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:text="جمع کل : "
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                            android:textColor="@color/textColorGray" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtSum"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:text="250000 تومان"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                            android:textColor="@color/textColorGray" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtDeliveryTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/txtSumTitle"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:text="هزینه حمل : "
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                            android:textColor="@color/textColorGray" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtDelivery"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/txtSum"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:text="رایگان"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                            android:textColor="@color/textColorGray" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/solid_line_no_border_less_round">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnPayInvoice"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="-5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/gradiant_payment_full_rounded"
                            android:text="پرداخت"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnPayInvoice"
                            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btnPayInvoice"
                            android:text="مبلغ قابل پرداخت :"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                            android:textColor="@color/textColorGray" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtSumInvoice"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                            android:text="250000 تومان"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                            android:textColor="@color/textColorGray" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainBottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/btnSummary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_basket_summary" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                <com.nex3z.notificationbadge.NotificationBadge
                    android:id="@+id/allBadge"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    app:nbBackground="@drawable/badge_circle"
                    app:nbMaxTextLength="2"
                    app:nbTextColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:nbTextSize="10sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_forward" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_backward" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dimLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Menu Layouts ... -->
<io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/topButtonsLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtMainTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="#1a7acf" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btnMenuLayout"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:padding="0dp"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_menu"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnBackMenu"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_back_top" />

            <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                android:id="@+id/btnPremium"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
                app:lottie_fileName="diamonds.json"
                app:lottie_loop="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/transparent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

How do I know what layout is this gray shadow?

Comment: Something's going out of order with your layout, most likely. That shadow (the scrim) will still be applied, even if you can't see the drawer. For most cases with `DrawerLayout`, you should have only one main content `View`, and one drawer `View`. You currently have two `View`s that are being treated as content `View`s. The `ScrollView` is the only one `DrawerLayout` will consider a drawer.